# Error message in partial rendered twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I was doing exercises from RoR Tutorial, and ran into a weird problem where the error message rendered twice.

`new.html.slim`

```
- provide(:title,'Sign up')

h1 Sign up
div class="row"
    div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3"
        = form_for(@user,html:{role:"form"}) do |f|
            = render 'shared/error_messages'
            div class="form-group"
                = f.label :name
                = f.text_field :name, class:"form-control"
            div class="form-group"
                = f.label :email
                = f.text_field :email, class:"form-control"
            div class="form-group"
                = f.label :password
                = f.password_field :password, class:"form-control"
            div class="form-group"
                = f.label :password_confirmation,"Confirmation"
                = f.password_field :password_confirmation, class:"form-control"

            = f.submit "Create Account", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary"
```

In this code (line 7) I am rendering a partial `shared/error_messages`.  The page is being called like so:

`users_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Any ideas?

edit : added partial

```
= if @user.errors.any?
    div#error_explanation
        div class="alert alert-danger"
            | The form has
            = "#{@user.errors.count}"
            | error(s)
        ul
            - @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
                li
                    = "#{msg}"
```

Comment: is it an actual Double Render Error, or are you just getting something displayed twice on the page?

Comment: I am getting this 'shared/error_messages' bit displayed twice on the page, and when i googled about this,i assumed that the problem was caused because i called 'new' in users_controller.rb.

Comment: Can you paste the content of this partial ?

Comment: `= if @user.errors.any?` just change '=' to '-'

Comment: wow. it fixed the problem. no idea why.

Comment: I am not familiar with this 'slim' syntax, but it seems the `=` is used when you want to output a value, whereas the `-` is used to control what is being executed (used with `if`, `each` statements etc.). Similar to `<%=` and `<%` in `.html.erb` files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error in your partial for

= if @user.errors.any?

to

- if @user.errors.any?